# C# : Linq in Entity Framework - slow performance when Skip, Take. But in very "strange" case

Tags: c#, sql, performance, entity-framework, linq

I am making a table that outputs data. I always filter by "date" and there is also the possibility of searching (by string fields).

The following situation: the selected period has 34 elements. But the download takes 15 seconds.

Next I checked:

1. If you remove the line with Skip/Take, everything works fine
2. If you add some value (so that there are exactly 34 elements as a result) in the search, everything works quickly.

That is, the problem is reproduced at the moment of Take / Skip.

- Take = 36
- Skip = 0

Here are the generated queries (without and with search)

Without:

```sql
Executed DbCommand (14,018ms) [Parameters=[@__user_Id_0='?' (DbType 
= Int32), @__p_1='?' (DbType = DateTime), @__p_2='?' (DbType = DateTime), @__p_3='?' (DbType = Int32), @__p_4='?' (DbType = Int32)],
CommandType='Text', Com mandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [t3].[ID0] AS [Id], CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [t3].[ID0]) AS [IdString], [t3].[Date], [t3].[AbsTransCount] AS [Number],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [t3].[AbsTransCount]) AS [NumberString], CASE
          WHEN [t3].[ID2] IS NOT NULL THEN [g].[Name]
          ELSE [g0].[Name]
      END AS [DepartmentName], COALESCE(CASE
          WHEN [t3].[ID2] IS NOT NULL THEN [g1].[Name]
          ELSE [g2].[Name]
      END, [g3].[Name]) AS [SubdivisionName], CASE
          WHEN [t3].[ID2] IS NOT NULL THEN [t3].[GroupID0]
          ELSE [t3].[GroupID]
      END AS [DepartmentId], COALESCE(CASE
          WHEN [t3].[ID2] IS NOT NULL THEN [g1].[GroupID]
          ELSE [g2].[GroupID]
      END, [t3].[GroupID1]) AS [SubdivisionId], [t3].[Number0] AS [TrkSerrialNumber], [t3].[Fuel] AS [FuelName], [t3].[ID4] AS [FuelId],
CASE
          WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM((((COALESCE([t3].[Name], '') + CAST(N' ' AS varchar(50))) + COALESCE([t3].[Middlename], '')) + CAST(N' ' AS
varchar(50))) + COALESCE([t3].[Surname], ''))) = '' THEN NULL
          ELSE (((COALESCE([t3].[Name], '') + CAST(N' ' AS varchar(50))) + COALESCE([t3].[Middlename], '')) + CAST(N' ' AS
varchar(50))) + COALESCE([t3].[Surname], '')
      END AS [PersonName], (COALESCE([t3].[Tmodel], N'') + CAST(N' ' AS nvarchar(100))) + COALESCE([t3].[Number], N'') AS [TransportName],
[t3].[ID1] AS [TransportId], [t3].[ID2] AS [PersonId], [t3].[Value],
[t3].[Value] / 1000 AS  [ValueLitr], [a].[GroupID] AS [GroupId],
[a].[Name] AS [AzsName], [t3].[Value15], [t3].[FuelDensity],
[t3].[FuelTemperature], [t3].[FuelDensity] * CAST([t3].[Value] AS
float) AS [FuelWeight], [t3].[TRKid] AS [TrkId], [t3].[AZSid0 ] AS
[AzsId]
      FROM (
          SELECT [t].[ID] AS [ID0], [t].[AZSid] AS [AZSid0], [t].[Date], [t].[FuelDensity], [t].[FuelTemperature], [t].[TRKid],
[t].[Value], [t].[Value15], [t0].[ID] AS [ID1], [t0].[GroupID],
[t0].[Number], [t0].[Tmodel], [p].[ID]  AS [ID2], [p].[GroupID] AS
[GroupID0], [p].[Middlename], [p].[Name], [p].[Surname], [t1].[AzsID]
AS [AzsID1], [t1].[GroupID] AS [GroupID1], [t1].[Number] AS [Number0],
[l0].[ID] AS [ID4], [l0].[Fuel], [t2].[AbsTransCount]
          FROM [LoginAzsAccess] AS [l]
          INNER JOIN [TRKallTransactions] AS [t] ON [l].[AzsID] = [t].[AZSid]
          LEFT JOIN [Transport] AS [t0] ON [t].[TransportID] = [t0].[ID]
          LEFT JOIN [Persons] AS [p] ON [t].[PersonID] = [p].[ID]
          LEFT JOIN [TRK] AS [t1] ON [t].[TRKid] = [t1].[ID]
          LEFT JOIN [LibFuelTypes] AS [l0] ON [t].[FUELid] = [l0].[ID]
          LEFT JOIN [TRKofflineData] AS [t2] ON [t].[LinkObjectID] = [t2].[ID]
          WHERE (([l].[AccessLevel] 6) AND ([l].[LoginID] = @__user_Id_0)) AND (([t].[Date] >= @__p_1) AND ([t].[Date] <= @__p_2))
          ORDER BY [t].[ID] DESC
          OFFSET @__p_3 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_4 ROWS ONLY
      ) AS [t3]
      LEFT JOIN [Groups] AS [g] ON [t3].[GroupID0] = [g].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Groups] AS [g0] ON [t3].[GroupID] = [g0].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Groups] AS [g1] ON [g].[GroupID] = [g1].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Groups] AS [g2] ON [g0].[GroupID] = [g2].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Groups] AS [g3] ON [t3].[GroupID1] = [g3].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Azs] AS [a] ON [t3].[AzsID1] = [a].[ID]
      ORDER BY [t3].[ID0] DESC
```

With search(all fine):

```sql
 Executed DbCommand (55ms) [Parameters=[@__user_Id_0='?' (DbType =
Int32), @__p_1='?' (DbType = DateTime), @__p_2='?' (DbType =
DateTime), @__p_3='?' (DbType = Int32), @__p_4='?' (DbType = Int32)],
CommandType='Text', Command Timeout='30']
      SELECT [t].[ID] AS [Id], CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [t].[ID]) AS [IdString], [t].[Date], [t2].[AbsTransCount] AS [Number],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [t2].[AbsTransCount]) AS [NumberString], CASE
          WHEN [p].[ID] IS NOT NULL THEN [g].[Name]
          ELSE [g1].[Name]
      END AS [DepartmentName], COALESCE(CASE
          WHEN [p].[ID] IS NOT NULL THEN [g0].[Name]
          ELSE [g2].[Name]
      END, [g3].[Name]) AS [SubdivisionName], CASE
          WHEN [p].[ID] IS NOT NULL THEN [p].[GroupID]
          ELSE [t0].[GroupID]
      END AS [DepartmentId], COALESCE(CASE
          WHEN [p].[ID] IS NOT NULL THEN [g0].[GroupID]
          ELSE [g2].[GroupID]
      END, [t1].[GroupID]) AS [SubdivisionId], [t1].[Number] AS [TrkSerrialNumber], [l0].[Fuel] AS [FuelName], [l0].[ID] AS [FuelId],
CASE
          WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM((((COALESCE([p].[Name], '') + CAST(N' ' AS varchar(50))) + COALESCE([p].[Middlename], '')) + CAST(N' ' AS
varchar(50))) + COALESCE([p].[Surname], ''))) = '' THEN NULL
          ELSE (((COALESCE([p].[Name], '') + CAST(N' ' AS varchar(50))) + COALESCE([p].[Middlename], '')) + CAST(N' ' AS
varchar(50))) + COALESCE([p].[Surname], '')
      END AS [PersonName], (COALESCE([t0].[Tmodel], N'') + CAST(N' ' AS nvarchar(100))) + COALESCE([t0].[Number], N'') AS [TransportName],
[t0].[ID] AS [TransportId], [p].[ID] AS [PersonId], [t].[Value],
[t].[Value] / 1000 AS [Val ueLitr], [a].[GroupID] AS [GroupId],
[a].[Name] AS [AzsName], [t].[Value15], [t].[FuelDensity],
[t].[FuelTemperature], [t].[FuelDensity] * CAST([t].[Value] AS float)
AS [FuelWeight], [t].[TRKid] AS [TrkId], [t].[AZSid] AS [AzsId]
      FROM [LoginAzsAccess] AS [l]
      INNER JOIN [TRKallTransactions] AS [t] ON [l].[AzsID] = [t].[AZSid]
      LEFT JOIN [Transport] AS [t0] ON [t].[TransportID] = [t0].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Persons] AS [p] ON [t].[PersonID] = [p].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [TRK] AS [t1] ON [t].[TRKid] = [t1].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [LibFuelTypes] AS [l0] ON [t].[FUELid] = [l0].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [TRKofflineData] AS [t2] ON [t].[LinkObjectID] = [t2].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Groups] AS [g] ON [p].[GroupID] = [g].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Groups] AS [g0] ON [g].[GroupID] = [g0].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Groups] AS [g1] ON [t0].[GroupID] = [g1].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Groups] AS [g2] ON [g1].[GroupID] = [g2].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Groups] AS [g3] ON [t1].[GroupID] = [g3].[ID]
      LEFT JOIN [Azs] AS [a] ON [t1].[AzsID] = [a].[ID]
      WHERE (([l].[AccessLevel] 6) AND ([l].[LoginID] = @__user_Id_0)) AND ((((((((((CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [t].[ID]) LIKE
N'%1%') OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [t2].[AbsTransCount]) LIKE N'%1%'))
OR (COALESCE(CASE
          WHEN [p].[ID] IS NOT NULL THEN [g0].[Name]
          ELSE [g2].[Name]
      END, [g3].[Name]) LIKE '%1%')) OR (CASE
          WHEN [p].[ID] IS NOT NULL THEN [g].[Name]
          ELSE [g1].[Name]
      END LIKE '%1%')) OR ([a].[Name] LIKE N'%1%')) OR ([t1].[Number] LIKE N'%1%')) OR ([l0].[Fuel] LIKE '%1%')) OR (CASE
          WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM((((COALESCE([p].[Name], '') + CAST(N' ' AS varchar(50))) + COALESCE([p].[Middlename], '')) + CAST(N' ' AS
varchar(50))) + COALESCE([p].[Surname], ''))) = '' THEN NULL
          ELSE (((COALESCE([p].[Name], '') + CAST(N' ' AS varchar(50))) + COALESCE([p].[Middlename], '')) + CAST(N' ' AS
varchar(50))) + COALESCE([p].[Surname], '')
      END LIKE '%1%')) OR ((COALESCE([t0].[Tmodel], N'') + CAST(N' ' AS nvarchar(100))) + COALESCE([t0].[Number], N'') LIKE N'%1%')) AND
(([t].[Date] >= @__p_1) AND ([t].[Date] <= @__p_2)))
      ORDER BY [t].[ID] DESC
      OFFSET @__p_3 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_4 ROWS ONLY
```

Code:

```
public static async Task<Tuple<List<T>, int>GetFilteredAndTotal<T>(this IQueryable<Tenumerator, FilterContainer filter)
{
    if (filter == null)
    {
        int c = await enumerator.CountAsync();
        return new Tuple<List<T>, int>(await enumerator.ToListAsync(), c);
    }

    if (filter.Where != null)
    {
        enumerator = enumerator.Where(filter.Where);
    }

    int count = await enumerator.CountAsync();

    if (filter.OrderBy != null)
    {
        enumerator = enumerator.OrderBy(filter.OrderBy);
    }

    if (filter.Take != -1)
    {
        // if I comment this - all work fine
        enumerator = enumerator.Skip(filter.Skip).Take(filter.Take);
    }

    return new Tuple<List<T>, int>(await enumerator.ToListAsync(), count);
}
```

Linq:

```
  var trkTransactions =
                from laa in _repoLoginAzsAccess.Get()
                join tt in _repoTrkallTransaction.Get() on laa.AzsId equals tt.Azsid
                join transport in _repoTransport.Get() on tt.TransportId equals transport.Id into t
                from transport in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join person in _repoPerson.Get() on tt.PersonId equals person.Id into p
                from person in p.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join trk in _repoTrk.Get() on tt.Trkid equals trk.Id into trk1
                from trk in trk1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join fuel in _repoLibFuelType.Get() on tt.Fuelid equals fuel.Id into f
                from fuel in f.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join trkOff in _repoTrkOfflineData.Get() on tt.LinkObjectId equals trkOff.Id into trkooff1
                from trkOff in trkooff1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where laa.AccessLevel > 6 && laa.LoginId == user.Id
                orderby tt.Id descending
                
                select new TrkTransactionModel
                {
                    Id = tt.Id,
                    IdString = tt.Id.ToString(),
                    Date = tt.Date,
                    // TODO ????
                    Number = trkOff.AbsTransCount,
                    NumberString = trkOff.AbsTransCount.ToString(),
                    DepartmentName = person!=null ? person.Group.Name : transport.Group.Name,
                    SubdivisionName = (person!=null ? person.Group.GroupNavigation.Name : transport.Group.GroupNavigation.Name) ?? trk.Group.Name,
                    DepartmentId = person!=null ? person.GroupId : transport.GroupId,
                    SubdivisionId = (person!=null ? person.Group.GroupNavigation.GroupId : transport.Group.GroupNavigation.GroupId) ?? trk.GroupId,
                    TrkSerrialNumber = trk.Number,
                    FuelName = fuel.Fuel,
                    FuelId = fuel.Id,
                    PersonName = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.Name + ' ' + person.Middlename + ' ' + person.Surname)
                        ? null
                        : (person.Name + ' ' + person.Middlename + ' ' + person.Surname),
                    TransportName = transport.Tmodel + ' ' + transport.Number,
                    TransportId = transport.Id,
                    PersonId = person.Id,
                    Value = tt.Value,
                    ValueLitr = tt.Value / 1000,
                    GroupId = trk.Azs.GroupId,
                    AzsName = trk.Azs.Name,
                    Value15 = tt.Value15,
                    FuelDensity = ((double) tt.FuelDensity),
                    FuelTemperature = ((double) tt.FuelTemperature),
                    FuelWeight = ((double) (tt.FuelDensity * tt.Value)),
                    TrkId = tt.Trkid,
                    AzsId = tt.Azsid,
                };
```

Comment: `OFFSET ... FETCH` are a bit notorious for producing potentially terrible query plans, because the engine has to count out rows exactly. If you have a `FETCH` of 36 with only 34 rows matching, the engine may spend a very long time indeed searching for those final 2 rows in the full result set (which it will never find). The same can happen to a lesser extent with `TOP`, but in that case it's more likely that an index will save the day. There isn't much you can do about this other than making sure your "main" criteria are sufficiently selective (limited period) and supported by indexes.

Comment: I will note that this is a big query with a ton of joins. If those `LEFT JOIN`s only ever select single rows with more data to join up to the "main" table (`TRKallTransactions`), so not a 1-N relationship, you may get better results explicitly filtering that table first (using the period) so the engine doesn't get bogged down trying to use other, less effective indexes in an attempt to bring down the cardinality. This may require the use of a table-valued function and/or explicit index hint, though, which is not as convenient to integrate into EF. A columnstore index is another option.

Comment: A lot of joins, show your LINQ query,

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv add linq in post

Comment: One issue with highly dynamic attempts like this is that the database indexing and execution plan caching cannot be counted on in all possible permutations that you might send it. You also need to guard that Skip/Take cannot be used if an OrderBy clause hasn't been provided.  If instead you set up expensive queries to be more explicit (think offering users a scenario-based search option with more limited relevant options rather than a "query anything any way" type solution) then queries can be simplified and indexed properly to avoid weird exceptions to the expectation.